# Run a thread from UI thread without blocking UI thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, ui-thread

I have a boolean property in my viewmodel that binds to a property in my view. When this property changes to true I would like to make a service call without blocking the UI thread, so my view can carry on working.
So far I have:

```
    private bool _isLoadingAnimationVisible = true;
    public bool IsLoadingAnimationVisible
    {
        get { return _isLoadingAnimationVisible; }
        set
        {
            _isLoadingAnimationVisible = value;
            if (IsLoadingAnimationVisible)
            {
                Task t = new Task(() => { LoadStuff(SelectedSomething.Id, SelectedDate, false); });
                t.Start();
            }
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsLoadingAnimationVisible");
        }
    }
```

I don't think the method LoadStuff is important but this task t is currently blocking my UI thread. I was wondering whether there was a way to execute thread t while keeping the UI thread free.

Comment: Just a small thing - I'd suggest checking `_isLoadingAnimationVisible != value` before making the call. A common patter is to check if the new value equals the old value and return if they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
if (IsLoadingAnimationVisible)
{
    new Thread(delegate() {
                           LoadStuff(SelectedSomething.Id, SelectedDate, false);
                          }).Start();
}
```

Make sure you are not updating UI from `LoadStuff`.

Comment: What if I am updating UI from my `LoadStuff` method? would this way not work?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(()=>{get the bool})
```

You need to await a task for it to be async. The factory is a clean way of doing this.